# Convergence in probability to sequence which converges to 0

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am trying to prove a theorem. For a specific part, I believe to have a solution, but I am not sure. $\text{plim}$ denotes convergence in probability. Here is what I am trying to show:

Assume $m = o(n)$. Assume we have $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; X_n = \frac{m}{n}c$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and real valued infinite sequence of random variables $X_n$. Then obviously $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{m}{n}c = 0$, but I want to show that furthermore $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; X_n = 0$. Here is my proof:

$P(|X_n|\geq \epsilon) = P(|X_n - \frac{m}{n}c + \frac{m}{n}c| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(|X_n - \frac{m}{n}c| + |\frac{m}{n}c| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(|X_n - \frac{m}{n}c| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}) + P(|\frac{m}{n}c| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2})$

Both of the probabilities obviously go to 0 in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I could not find this result anywhere in the literature so I have doubts if my proof is right. On the other hand, it is simple to show (?), so maybe just too trivial for a textbook?

Comment: $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; X_n = \frac{m}{n}c$ does not make sense. If you mean $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; [X_n - \frac{m}{n}c]=0$ then your argument is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much!

Comment: However, do you know if the continuous mapping theorem would generalize to this? So, do $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} [X^{(1)}_n - c^{(1)}_n] = 0$ and $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} [X^{(2)}_n - c^{(2)}_n] = 0$ imply e.g. $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} [X^{(1)}_n \cdot X^{(2)}_n - c^{(1)}_n \cdot c^{(2)}_n] = 0$?

Comment: No. Counter-example: $X_n^{(1)}=c_n^{(1)}=n,X_n^{(2)}=c_n^{(2)}=n+n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Right, thanks. Then I need to restart my proof I guess. But thanks for the help anyway! Do you know any good literature about this?